# How to tell if a django DB-based session has expired in browser?

Tags: django, session, cookies

I'm presently using the default database-backed sessions model in my django application. The front end is an SPA that interfaces with a REST API, and has an asynchronous login so that the user doesn't lose their page when their session times out. I'm trying to detect when the session has timed out in the browser, so that the login modal may be shown.

However:

- If the `User` is no longer authorized to perform an API request
  because they're no longer logged in, they get a HTTP403.
- If the `User` tries to access object instances that belong to other `Users`,
  they also get a HTTP403.

So I need to distinguish between the two 403s. My immediate instinct was to compare the expiry of the `sessionid` cookie and `now`, but:

1. The cookie is `httpOnly`
2. The expiry is not set

Hence my question: how can I tell, in the browser, if my django session has expired?

Comment: You can HTTP401 when user is not authorized and HTTP403 If the User tries to access object instances that belong to other Users

Comment: It's not exactly what you're asking but I think you'd be better off using JWT instead of sessions. It's more suitable for a REST API, you can refresh the token regularly, and it's possible to decode the token in Javascript in order to retrieve the expiry time, so you can check to see if it has expired without making an HTTP request. If you're using Django REST framework it's straightforward to use JWT.

Comment: I'm going to accept the 401 answer becuase that's the answer to the question I asked, but I agree that tokens would be better. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per standard HTTP401 is used for Unauthorized access. You can find more info about HTTP401 here. 
https://httpstatuses.com/401

Comment: This is totally unrelated to what OP has asked. You provided the last step to be done as sending 401 which is correct but its not an answer